# How to trigger Metrics calculation at the time of prometheus endpoint call

Tags: java, prometheus, micronaut, micrometer

I am trying to configure my Micronaut Application with Micrometer and Prometheus. I want to do some calculation at the time of prometheus endpoint call. Can someone guide me here?

I tried to define a bean in Micronaut as follows, but it didn't get triggered and no metric with name SampleMetric was there:

```
@Prototype
public class MyBean {

  @Inject
  MeterRegistry registry;

  public MyBean() {
    Gauge.builder("SampleMetric", 12).register(registry);
    // I also tried the following but that also didn't work
    //registry.gauge("SampleMetric", 12);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this guide can help: https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-metrics-gradle-java.html

Comment: In the example you shared they are triggering it through scheduled annotation in a service. I want to do it when metrics endpoint (/prometheus) is called.

Comment: If you want to set a metric only when the Micronaut Metric Prometheus endpoint is call, you are going to have to create your own version of the endpoint (https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-registry-prometheus/src/main/java/io/micronaut/configuration/metrics/micrometer/prometheus/management/PrometheusEndpoint.java) and `@Replace` on your class. (Not sure it will work, since I have never tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gauge`s are queried every time the Prometheus registry is scraped (prometheus endpoint call).
Also `Gauge` supports providing your own state object and own method that fetches the current value, please see the docs: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_gauge_fluent_builder

If you follow the example in the docs:

```java
Gauge.builder("gauge", myObj, myObj::gaugeValue).register(registry);
```

`myObj.gaugeValue()` is called every time the prometheus endpoint is called.